# Problem with The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

i have this message while executing this SQL request in SQL server ,

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

this is my SQL request :

```
set language english

SELECT DISTINCT TOP (10000)
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TPP.NoPersonne,
                                       TROC.reftiers,
                                       CONVERT(datetime, TSIT.DateAffiliation, 120),
                                       CONVERT(datetime, COALESCE(TSIT.DateSortie, '31/12/9999'), 120)
                          ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, COALESCE(TCT.DateFinValidite, '31/12/9999'), 120) DESC) AS RowCount1,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TPP.NoPersonne,
                                       TROC.reftiers,
                                       CONVERT(datetime, TSIT.DateAffiliation, 120),
                                       CONVERT(datetime, COALESCE(TSIT.DateSortie, '31/12/9999'), 120)
                          ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, COALESCE(TP.DateFin, '31/12/9999'), 120) DESC) AS RowCount2
FROM stock.TPersonnePhysique TPP
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[ZED_PP_ACTIVE] PPA ON TPP.OID = PPA.OID_PP
     INNER JOIN stock.TRoleAssure TRO ON TPP.oid = TRO.reftiers
                                     AND TPP.flag_delete = 0
                                     AND TRO.flag_delete = 0
     INNER JOIN stock.TSitContractAff TSIT ON TRO.oid = TSIT.refroletiers
                                          AND TSIT.flag_delete = 0
                                          AND CONVERT(datetime, ISNULL(TSIT.DateSortie, '01/01/9999'), 120) > DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
     INNER JOIN stock.TLienContratAdherentCol TLI ON TCON.RefLienContratAdherentColl = TLI.oid
                                                 AND TLI.flag_delete = 0
     LEFT JOIN(stock.TRattachementPopulation TRP
               INNER JOIN stock.JDonneesComplementaires_RattPop JDC_RP ON JDC_RP.RefRattachementPopulation = TRP.OID
                                                                      AND JDC_RP.Flag_Delete = 0
                                                                      AND TRP.Flag_Delete = 0
               INNER JOIN stock.TContratTravail TCT ON TCT.OID = JDC_RP.ListDonneesComplementaires
                                                   AND TCT.Flag_Delete = 0
                                                   AND TCT.CategorieProfessionnelle <> ''
                                                   AND TCT.CategorieProfessionnelle IS NOT NULL)ON TRP.RefMembre = TRO.OID
                                                                                               AND ((CONVERT(datetime, TCT.DateDebutValidite, 120) >= CONVERT(datetime, TSIT.DateAffiliation, 120)
                                                                                                 AND CONVERT(datetime, TCT.DateDebutValidite, 120) <= CONVERT(datetime, COALESCE(TSIT.DateSortie, '2999-12-31'), 120))
                                                                                                 OR (CONVERT(datetime, TSIT.DateAffiliation, 120) >= CONVERT(datetime, TCT.DateDebutValidite, 120)
                                                                                                 AND CONVERT(datetime, TSIT.DateAffiliation, 120) < CONVERT(datetime, COALESCE(TCT.DateFinValidite, '2999-12-31'), 120)));
```

i want to fix this message please :(

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1)` without an `ORDER BY`? When is a `TOP 1` going to produce more than 1 distinct row (hint: it won't) and are you *really* happy with your solution returning any arbitrary row?

Comment: Show sample input data and desired output, and explain why it maps that way.

Comment: As for the problem, a clause like `AND ((CONVERT(datetime, TCT.DateDebutValidite, 120) >= CONVERT(datetime, TSIT.DateAffiliation, 120)` **strongly** implies that `TCT.DateDebutValidite` and `TSIT.DateAffiliation` aren't stored as a `datetime`; that's your ***real*** problem. Fix the design; `varchar` isn't a one size fits all data type.

Comment: it's only en example, the Query return more than 23 millions lines.

Comment: *"it's only en example"* Then why add `DISTINCT TOP(1)` when it's not in your query? That only derails your question, and the combination of that, and the lack of an `ORDER BY` has a high chance to derail your question.

Answer (score 1):

Do not store dates as strings!  It only leads to problems, such as this.

One method to get around the error is to use `try_convert()`:

```
try_convert(datetime, TSIT.DateAffiliation, 120)
```

Instead of failing, this returns `NULL` so the results will be filtered out.

You can find the offending values using:

```
select TSIT.DateAffiliation
from stock.TSitContractAff TSIT
where try_convert(datetime, TSIT.DateAffiliation, 120) is null and
      TSIT.DateAffiliation is not null;
```

Note:  You will need to do this for all the dates in your query.  You should really put this effort into fixing the data model rather than fixing the queries.  That is, use proper date/time data types, rather than strings.